# unity setup firebase FCM plus Facebook for android

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried the messaging app from quickstart-unity-master and it was working fine on it's own but when I have added the Facebook plugin the following happened:

The firebase FCM is initializing successfully but I am no longer receiving the `OnMessageReceived` and `OnTokenReceived`.

It has probably something to do with the `com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity` activity not receiving the events,  but I am not sure what is wrong since the Android manifest is still the same after adding facebook.

I am using facebook 7.10.1

Here is my android manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="${applicationId}" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <!-- The MessagingUnityPlayerActivity is a class that extends
         UnityPlayerActivity to work around a known issue when receiving
         notification data payloads in the background. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb11111111111111" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider233093877143960" android:exported="true" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was some missing dependencies, at first i only included what is needed by both SDK and tried them separately and they worked, but together didn't work for some reason;

the solution was to switch the build system from internal to gradle , then you don't have to worry about the max DEX methods and you can let the google play resolver download all the needed JAR and AAR;